# DAC not working

Tags: fpga, dac

I have a [DAC](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/48587/AD/AD9775BSV.html) connected to an FPGA, which I cannot get to work. The FPGA, in a loop, sends in the maximum value to the data pins and incrementally goes down to 0.

I have checked with a scope that the data pins are changing as expected, and I have checked that the clock is OK. Nevertheless, the output analogue signals `IOUTA` and `IOUTB` stay constant (around 1V).

The DAC can be configured through an SPI channel, but the default configuration should work out of the box. What could I be doing wrong for my DAC to stay constant despite the data pins changing?

Comment: Have you checked that `SELECT` is high and therefore routing to `IOUT`? Just something to check that you didn't mention.

Comment: Aha! That was indeed wrong. Recompiling, and waiting for results. Thanks.

Comment: @embedded.kyle: Nope, didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you have connected to the outputs? They're current outputs, so 1 V as output can't be right. Connecting a load resistor to ground should convert the output current into a voltage.

Comment: Each differential pair wire is connected a pull-down resistor, and the differential pairs are connected to [EMI filters](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/117729/MURATA/DLW21HN900SQ2.html).

Comment: @RandomBlue - FS output current is typically 10 mA, if your resistor values are too high the signal may be clipping.

Comment: @Randomblue - can you post the part of the schematic around the DAC?